# Java Desktop-App to Java-Web-App

Tags: java, jsp

I am new to Java-Web-Programming and my Non-GUI Netbeans-Codes are compiling well whenever I place the JSP tags, but my GUI Netbeans-Codes are full of errors whenever I place the JSP tags:<%! %> and <% %>. 
Below is one of my Netbeans-GUI codes for a simple "Salary Tagging System" with 3 labels corresponding to 3 textfields(dspID, dspNAME,dspSAL).
What is the right JSP-Tagging way?

```
public class Employee extends javax.swing.JFrame {

   // Variables declaration                     
private javax.swing.JTextArea dispAREA;
private javax.swing.JTextField dispID;
private javax.swing.JTextField dispNAME;
private javax.swing.JTextField dispSAL;
private javax.swing.JButton findBUTTON;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
// End of variables declaration    


public Employee() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    findBUTTON = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    dispID = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    dispNAME = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    dispAREA = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    dispSAL = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    findBUTTON.setText("Find");
    findBUTTON.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            findBUTTONActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setText("Employee ID");

    jLabel2.setText("Name");

    dispAREA.setColumns(20);
    dispAREA.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(dispAREA);

    jLabel3.setText("Salary");

    dispSAL.setText("                                     ");


}// </editor-fold>                        

private void findBUTTONActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           


    try{

        Class.forName( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" );
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Emp","root","");
            Statement statement = con.createStatement();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM EmpInfo ";
        query +="WHERE EmpInfo = "+this.dispID.getText();

        if(this.dispNAME.getText().length() != 0){
            query +=" and Name = '"+this.dispNAME.getText()+"'";
        }

            if(this.dispSAL.getText().length() != 0){
            query +=" and Salary = '"+this.dispSAL.getText()+"'";
        }

        //dispAREA.append("\nYour Query is :"+query+"\n");

        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

        boolean moreRecords = rs.next();
        if(!moreRecords){
            dispAREA.append("Sorry,no match!");

                this.dispID.setText("");

        }
        do{
            this.dispNAME.setText(rs.getString(2));
                    this.dispSAL.setText(rs.getString(3));
            this.dispAREA.setText(rs.getString(4));
        }while(rs.next());
        statement.close();
        con.close();

    }

    catch(SQLException e){
        dispAREA.append("");
        //outputjTextArea.append(e.getStackTrace().toString());
        //e.printStackTrace();


    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        //e.printStackTrace();
        dispAREA.append("");
    }

}                                          

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new Employee().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

}`

Comment: why you need jsp tags in GUI app ? jsp/servlet technology developed for web apps not desktop GUIs.

Comment: @Viraj-Its because I want to convert it to a Web-App.

Comment: Converting to a web app is a much more involved process than just using JSP. You need to learn HTTP, AJAX, Javascript CSS, HTM...

Comment: @bhspencer-I think they developed JSP and Servlets to runaway from the cumbersomeness of CSS,long HTMLs and Jscript. I have never tried AJAX though. Do you know any better alternative??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to make your application both gui and web capable would be to redesign it using the MVC principle. Put simply that separates the display part from data and processing.

Comment: @Marged-the MVC is what I have been avoiding all along,is there a better alternative? MVC once worked for me long time ago when I was doing a small class project. Let me give it a try.

Comment: @Shawn are we both talking of "model-view-controller" MVC ?

Comment: sure that's what am refrering to. But I was looking for a Java Swing Web-Enabler, something like AJAXSWING,WEBCREAM or JAVAWEBSTART but wont mess-up my code.

Comment: @Shawn so why didn't you mention this upfront in your question ? JSP and JavaWebstart for example are totally different ways to get something online